# Mobile App Development ...Which should I choose to use in the future?

Tags: mobile-development

Mobile App Development

-Native (java,swift)
-Xamarin
-React Native
-ionic
-what else?

...Which should I choose to use in the future and why?

I'm Thai ,Sorry for my language ...Thank U

Comment: You choose the one you're comfortable with and already know. If you're just starting out then pick any.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :)

Answer (score 1):

From my experience (So i might be wrong on some stuff):

-Native (java,swift):

native languages are cool is you have ressources(as employer), like time and money. Because you need 2 programmers to do 1 app on both systems. As programmer, these skills are valuable for your future employer but you (most of the time) can't do both (java and swift)

-Xamarin:

In my opinion, xamarin used to be cool when there was no "hybrid" solutions, it was really better than cordova in terms of performance

-ionic:

I spent a lot of time on ionic and the actual framework is pretty cool, big community etc. But actually, the performances arn't really good. I used Ionic for my prototypes where I didn't need to have a perfect native feel. Plus, Ionic is great if you already know a bit of HTML / CSS / JS. You can do a good app in no time.

-React Native

I switched to react 6 months ago and it's way better than Ionic. At first, the architecture is kinda hard to get but once you to everything is faster. The community grows really fast so does the plugins. The framwork is growing fast and the updates are frequent (about 1 by month) There's also the Expo tool who help's you to build on android and ios painless. The only problem with expo is, you can't use plugins who needs a reack-native link yet. Some of them are implemented over time but there's still some work for that. The Expo team is doing a really good job at giving us a tool that makes our deployements and framwork upgrades painless.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thank for commented :)